# How to create array from object?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I dont know what to call this array-looking object. But When I try to access elements in Php, I cant.

```
    {
    "message":"authenticated", 
      "data": {"id":713,"name":"Jamal","email":"abdurasulovsokhib@gmail.com","role":"user"}
    }
```

I want to access the elements like this. $array['message']=> expecting the outcome to be "authenticated". please help

Comment: What are you using PHP for?

Comment: I am using third party service in my website with PHP curl, and response they send back to my query is this format. But I want to format it PHP array so that I cant manipulate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$JSON = file_get_contents('UserData.json'); // Parsing JSON from file. You can use your own way.
$Array = json_decode($JSON, true); // JSON (string) to Array
echo $Array["message"]; // Output: authenticated
echo $Array["data"]["id"]; // Output: 713
```

Comment: I dont know why but it didnt work. I used early different approach $array=json_decode(json_encode(my_object)); it didnt work also. i think it is similiar